# Drupal Reducing attched items within node.tpl.php

Tags: drupal, fancybox

I have multiple images attached to a content type that I have set up with fancybox. Currently when viewing that node, all images are displayed. I only want to show the first image, then the rest within gallery mode.

I an struggling to figure out how to limit the diplays within (node.tpl.php) to only show the first attaced image.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using CCK to upload your attachments or the built-in module ?

I don't remember well exactly, but you've a "List" option, that allow you to show or not the attachment in the node.

After, with the $node object you can show the rest as you like throw node.tpl.php

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I am using CCK file field to upload multiple images. What is this 'list' option you mentioned? I cant find this. Do you mean within display fields <hidden>? I need this set to fancybox for gallery.

Comment: I ended up setting a one image from display and then the rest as display:none;. The one grid item would then open in gallery mode and shoe the hidden images.